# Is it possible to return a dynamic formula in VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, vlookup

I am looking for a possibility to use VLOOKUP in combination with a dynamic formula (or a different solution if possible).

A simplified problem is provided in the image below. Based on a category the number of outlets in a room is calculated. The number of outlets can either be a fixed amount or based on the total area of a room which is provided in a separate column.

What is the best method to apply this to a (much larger) sample?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "based on total area" is always a x per unitA, then enter it as a proportion, e.g.: `0.1a` instead of `1 per 10 m^2`, and use a formula that checks for the trailing 'a' and responds accordingly. e.g.:

```
=IF(RIGHT(VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$3,2,FALSE),1)="a",CEILING.MATH(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$3,2,FALSE),"a","")*C2),VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$3,2,FALSE))
```

[image]

(I used "Ceiling" to get the integer value. Replace with Floor or Round as needed).

Probably easier from a formula writing (and readability) POV would be a separate column that holds the `a` (or rather: a "fixed/proportional" column) and key off of that, but the result is the same.